# The priority of the output values in the plugin WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I developing a plugin that returns a table with the data. Exemplary code

```
 function text_print(){
  $data = data();
  echo "
      <table >
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th ></th>
          <th ></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td > $data </td>
          <td ></td>
          <td ></td>
          <td ></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  ";
  }
function data(){
return "something text jnjnm ";
}
```

In php works as it should - outputs the data in the table. After inserting the function in the WordPress plugin and run on text displays above the table.
[How it displays in WordPress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G0AX.png) # [How it have to displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDS7I.png)

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: in WordPress data displaying not in table.

Comment: how do you want to display it? Please add more information to your question and your example codes seems incomplete.

Comment: I added images. My code is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is your working code try below code may it helps you.

```
function text_print(){
  $data = some_data();
  $html = "
      <table >
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th ></th>
          <th ></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td > ".$data." </td>
          <td ></td>
          <td ></td>
          <td ></td>
        </tr>
      </table>";
    return  $html;

  }
function some_data(){
return "something text jnjnm ";
}
```

here what i did whatever html you are directly echo but i have stored in one `$html` variable then return. this is generally happens when we write any code for wordpress from function we should return our html instead of `echo` try above code may helps you.